# ImageIcon loads no image

Tags: java, image, swing, button

I'm trying to get image built from tiled set of images So to JPanel I'm adding JButtons with ImageIcons. All images are in folder with my classes (NetBeans), and they're named u1, u2, ..., u16. But on button there is no image shown. What am I doing wrong ?

```
   JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3)); 
   for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
        JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("u"+i+".jpg"), JLabel.CENTER);
        l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
        panel.add(l);
    }
```

Comment: Are there any console messages?

Answer (score 2):

NetBeans is probably not finding your image files. To test this, use the full name of the files (from the `C:/path/to/image.jpg` if you are in Windows, and from the `/path/to/image.jpg` if you are under something unix-like).

I recommend using

```
new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(fileName));
```

where `fileName` for something available at "classes/org/myorg/resources/image.jpg" should look like `org/myorg/resources/image.jpg`. This has the advantage that it will work regardless of the way you access your classes (through HTTP, in a jar-file, ...).